# Observing for insertion of new DOM nodes and calling a method on them

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, observer-pattern

I'm writing some javascript using jQuery to call a method on all nodes with class `datepicker`.

Here's what I have:

```
$('.datepicker').my_method();
```

This works as expected - it calls `my_method`.

However, I want to be able to call `my_method` on all *new* nodes that are inserted into the DOM with the class `datepicker`.

I want similar functionality to the `.live`  method, without specifying an `eventType`.

How do I go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what the [`.livequery` plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/) is for  :)

You use it like this

```
$('.datepicker').livequery(function() {
  $(this).my_method();
});
```

Alternatively, you can re-run your plugin when you're loading elements, say in the case of [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), like this:

```
$.ajax({
  //options..
  success: function(data) {
    $("#elementId").html(data);
    $(".datepicker", data).my_method();
  }
});
```

This method only runs on `.datepicker` elements in the response, not existing ones...so it's only running/doing the minimal amount of work.  This is the most efficient approach in terms of wasted observation code/processing, etc...but it's not always an option.

Comment: Nice! Went with `livequery` as I wasn't inserting with AJAX. Ta :)